# How to propagate permissions from reference file to all files in a directory in Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, file-permissions, acl

I'm trying to serve a web page locally using IIS, but I am having trouble programmatically setting the permissions for all the files in my `wwwroot` directory. When I use the `Set-Acl` PowerShell directive with a reference file that has the necessary permissions, I only see exactly two changes propagate: The owner is changed, and RW permissions for the group `IIS_USRS` are added.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $newAcl = Get-Acl C:\inetpub\wwwroot\
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ChildItem C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ -Recurse -Force | Set-Acl -AclObject $newAcl
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

[image: A screenshot of the permissions in wwwroot that I'd like propagated] [image: A screenshot of the permissions of a sample file in after using Set-Acl]
So my question is, what am I doing wrong? How can I get these more detailed permissions to propagate fully? (I've also tried checking and applying `Replace all existing inheritable permissions on all descendants with inheritable permissions from this object`, but it doesn't seem to help either.)

Comment: I have realised what the problem is. I was not specifying the directory with the originating permissions when I was trying to propagate the permissions to the sub files and directories. I have provided my solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are specifying the *originating* file or directory (and not an inheritor) for the permissions you want to copy?

If you specify (in  `$newAcl`) an inheritor to the permissions you want, then **`Set-Acl` will only propagate the permissions that the file itself has originally (that is, without having been inherited)** and you'll not see the inherited permissions on the files whose permissions you are setting.

To get the inherited permissions, you can either use [Helge Klein's SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/examples/managing-file-system-permissions-with-setacl-exe/) 
or you can specify an ancestral (higher up) directory or file in your `Get-Acl` assignment.

So if `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\` is inheriting a large part of its permissions from `C:\inetpub\`, then you'll want `$newAcl = Get-Acl C:\inetpub\` in the snippet PowerShell command you provided.